# MVC Repository patterns Bind Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, irepository

I am having hard time using Repository patterns, is it possible to create two repository patterns?? One for products, another for orders??

I failed to connect these repositories to databases. I know how to work with one repository, but two with IRepository where T: Entity I am getting lost. The question is whether I can create and will not volatile the rules if create ProductRepository and OrderRepository?

Answer (score 0):

Repository pattern is widely used in DDD (Domain-Driven-Design) you could check it here: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly. Also check this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

With regards to your question:

Yes you can use more than 1 repository. Look in this example I use nHibernate session:

```
// crud operations
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
        protected readonly ISession _session;

        public Repository(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public T Add(T entity)
        {
            _session.BeginTransaction();
            //_session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            _session.Save(entity);
            _session.Transaction.Commit();
            return entity;
        }
//...
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Add(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);
    T SaveOrUpdate(T entity);
    bool Delete(T entity);      
}
```

Then my repository looks like this:

```
public class ProjectRepository : Repository<Project>, IProjectRepository
{
 // Project specific operations 
}
public interface IProjectRepository : IRepository<Project>
    {       
        Project Add(Project entity);
        Project Update(Project entity);
        Project find_by_id(int id);
        Project find_by_id_and_user(int id, int user_id);
//..
}
```

Then using Ninject:

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
        }
```

Then in NinjectControllerFactory I load the modules:

```
 public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {

        private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NhibernateModule(), new RepositoryModule(), new DomainServiceModule());

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
        {
            //var bindings = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IUserService));

            if (controllerType == null)
                return null;
            return (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
        }
    }
```

NhibernateModule:

```
public class NhibernateModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            string connectionString =            
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlite_con"].ConnectionString;

            var helper = new NHibernateHelper(connectionString);

            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope();
            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InRequestScope();           

        }
    }
```

Then in RepositoryModule I use Ninject Conventions to automatically bind all repositories with their interfaces:

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;

    public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            IKernel ninjectKernel = this.Kernel;

            ninjectKernel.Scan(kernel =>
            {
                kernel.FromAssemblyContaining<ProjectRepository>();                
                kernel.BindWithDefaultConventions();
                kernel.AutoLoadModules();
                kernel.InRequestScope();                

            });

       }
    }
```

And in the end I basically inject Repository in the controller:

public class projectscontroller : basecontroller
{
    private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;

```
public projectscontroller(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
{
    _projectRepository = projectRepository;
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult my()
{
    int user_id = (User as CustomPrincipal).user_id;
    var projectList = _projectRepository.find_by_user_order_by_date(user_id);
    var projetsModel = new ProjectListViewModel(projectList);
    return View("my", projetsModel);
}
```

}

This way you just create new Repository and its Interface and it will be automatically injected to your controller.